# Winding number of a closed Archimedean spiral

Tags: geometry

Why the winding number in the image is different for these different points? Should not it be +3 for all? I really don't understand this...

http://s8.postimg.org/sda6gvdh1/windingnumberclosedarch.png

Comment: Please include the image in your question, in stead of posting a link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that it's different for the different points; it's just the wrong way around; $+1$ and $+3$ should be exchanged. The curve winds around the point in the centre three times, but only one of the loops encloses the outermost point.